# PayPal add to cart custom shipping address

Tags: php, html, paypal

I've got a 2 item gift shop where people can send gifts to other people and pay via paypal. My issue is that its annoying for customers to have to change their address on the paypal checkout screen.

Is there a way I could make it so that they enter their address on the same page as the checkout button and that is then sent to the paypal page and autofills the address stuff. I'm currently only using HTML but could use PHP if needed

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already let your useres fill in an address on your website, why would you create a paypal button where they again have to fill in an address? Simply fill out the address in your paypal form automatically using these submit HTML variables:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0J0VU

And set 'address_override' to 1 as stated on:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Comment: How could I implement this in HTML so that it grabs the values from the address form if possible? Thanks